# Mounting a IDE DVD writer in Fedora Linux

Tags: linux

I have a medical computer which has Fedora Linux as its OS and the optical drive is a IDE TEAC DVD recorder.  Most of the times the TEAC DVD drive is not working as the tray belts are broken. The DVD drive in these medical systems are only used for software updates and not otherwise. On one such system, I removed the defective TEAC drive and replaced with a new IDE HP DVD Recorder and the linux wouldn't read any CD's from this drive. The BIOS identifies it well. I am told that the computer would read TEAC drive as the driver is loaded in the OS, but I believe this is not correct information. How can I configure the Fedora Linux to read from my HP DVD writer as well?

Comment: As long is it's IDE, it should work out of the box, unless the hardware is broken. Does it come up in `dmesg`? What happens if you `mount` a data CD? What happens if you read an audio CD with `cdparanoia`, `mplayer cdda://` etc?

Comment: No idea...absolutely a newbie to Linux. It's a Linux medical computer and has a optical drive from TEAC. A brand new HP IDE drive when replaced does not work. Do I need to mount the drive?.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `lsscsi` when the HP recorder is installed. Did you actually use the TEAC recorder, i.e., do you know how to do this under Linux?

Comment: I am a windows user and a medical engineer. One of the medical system computers has a problem that it cant read from the drive and I assumed as in Windows, u just change the drive and it shouldn't make a difference. I am told by the guys from the software dev team that there is no way to mount another IDE drive in to the computer and it should be a TEAC drive. Doesn't make sense to be since it is a ATAPI interface and should be able to mount. So I opened up the PC and installed a working HP IDE drive in place of the TEAC and it comes up with " Cannot read from Drive" error.

Comment: Yes the computer works well from another working TEAC optical drive. Why only a TEAC IDE drive and why not another IDe optical drive?

Comment: Good question, as I said, I'd assume any IDE drive should work. (1) Please *do* edit the question with the output if `lsscsi` in a terminal window, to verify that the HP drive is recognized at all. (2) How do you usually access the IDE drive? With a program written by the software dev team? In any other way? Please update your question and describe what you do.

Comment: Thanks. I will run the command lsscsi in a terminal window and will post the output in both cases- with TEAC and HP drives. The IDE drive is accessed by the program written by the software Dev team. I will post more info to give clarity on this issue.

Comment: I think this question deserves more input from users. Some background info first. What version OS are you running? Is it up to date? Are you able to update and add software? Does the program written by the dev team have a configure file? Example is it looking for a specific device `/dev/sdX`.  I am a debian person perhaps a Fedora person could help with debug commands?